# Create PDF with Latex equations using Angular

Tags: angular, latex, pdf-generation, mathjax, pdfmake

I have an admin-panel application (written on Angular) to create math tests which should have button to create pdf file.I used **pdfMake** which converts html but this html is not written in DOM (all questions of test with images, etc). This generated pdf is very large and consists of 20-30 pages.

Problem is that there are math equations written in **MathJax** and they are well shown in admin-panel (MathJax converts equations to **svg**). I cannot take this svg tags from dom because I see only one question per site page. I wan to create same svg tags in .ts file of component to add it to my variable which at the end is converted by **pdfMake**. How can I do it?